# javax.persistence NamedQuery not working as expected

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, hql, named-query

I'm probably being dense about this but a query isn't returning the results I'm expecting...

I have two tables(entities): Properties and Landlords as follows:

Properties is made up of the fields (amongst others): Id, propertyRef and landLordsid (which is a many-to-one join to table Landlords).

Landlords is made up of the fields (amongst others): Id, landlordName and the one-to-many Collection for the join.

I want the query to return all the properties for the landlord as passed in via the Integer parameter 'landLord', e.g. if the parameter is 2 then filter for Properties.landLordsid that equals 2.  This is the NamedQuery I'm currently using but it returns all properties and doesn't seem to filter.

```
SELECT p 
from Properties p 
JOIN p.landLordsid l 
WHERE l.id = :landLord
```

Any ideas what's wrong with the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let hibernate do the joining for you:

This HQL should work:

```
from Properties p 
where p.landLord.id = :landLord
```

Note how the join is implied and that "select *" is also implied.

Comment: Thanks for your help Bohemian.  It turned out that I was passing an incorrect copy of a Map from a previous query to the application client, hence why the results didn't change!!  But at least now I've learnt that a join and a select can be implied.

Comment: It be a clearer example to write `where p.landLord = :landLord` or `p.landLord.id = :landLordId`. Personally I prefer the former.